# Excel VBA script "forced value by value in another cell"

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with 3 columns that drive calculations in a separate section. Two of the columns are manual input and the third is a dropdown menu where you can select "y" or "n". I am trying to write a VBA code that allows you to select "y" or "n" from the dropdown menu, but if either of the manual entry columns are "0" it will automatically force a value of "n".

Comment: You don't need VBA for a dropdown and you can just do an `if` statement to force a `n`.

Comment: But I need to have the option to manually select "y" or "n"

Comment: Hmm, how do you mean @findwindow? if he's using data validation for the dropdown in column 3 to set the value to "y" or "n" manually, how can he use a formula in that cell?

Comment: Formula overrides data validation.

Comment: Er no, if you have a cell with a formula and data validation for a list of "y,n" set up, and the user clicks the cell and chooses "y" the formula gets overwritten. He might have cases where neither cell is 0 and he wants the user to enter "n".. you could do it in another column with `IF(OR(A1=0,B1=0),"n",C1)` but not in the same cell.

Comment: @NickDewitt Secret helper cell... containing the formula... and add conditional formatting with `"n"` if formula outputs n... if you know what I mean... and simply checking for the secret cell instead of the one with dropdown...

Comment: Doing too many things at once.

Comment: know that feeling lol, well I have added an example without using VBA to my answer anyway so both options are there, but he did ask for vba so ill leave the event driven option there too

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1 (No code)**

You can add a fourth column, and set your other sheets to look at that column. If your values are in column A & B, your data validation is in column C, then you could do some simple logic in column D and use that value as the reference:

`=IF(OR(A1=0,B1=0),"n",C1)`

[image]

**OPTION 2 - VBA**

Use the change event on the worksheet to check the values in the row when any of the cells change, and update to "n" if either value is equal to 0:

Put this code inside the the module for the worksheet object you want it to run on (not in it's own module).

note: I have set this to only run on columns 1-3 (`Target.Column <=3`), you will need to change this if your columns are in different places.

Also, I added the `application.enableevents` lines to stop the cell change triggering another cell change event and entering an infinite loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Target.Worksheet

If Target.Column <= 3 Then
    If ws.Cells(Target.Row, 1) = 0 Or ws.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ws.Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "n"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. Only problem I have is that if I change the "n" vale back to a "y" value without changing the "0" value in the other cell it crashes my excel. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I added a line before and after changing the cell to stop events firing, cos you were probably entering an infinite loop (oops!) :D

Comment: Genius, Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, but can you mark this as the answer please